# Python : Get selected objects in outliner

Tags: python, select

To get the selected object in viewport, we use :

```
bpy.context.selected_objects
```

But in outliner, if i select some objects there, then what is the python function to get/collect the selected objects in outliner ?

Comment: It is `bpy.context.selected_objects` as well... Have a look at: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/search.html?q=outliner&check_keywords=yes&area=default

Comment: ... not if hidden or disabled... I don't think there is something to identify them in these cases.

Comment: @brockmann Thanks but  as lemon said , i can't use it. It ignores the hidden/disabled objects. Most the object that i select is disabled. So no API for this ?

Comment: Nope, can not find anything...

Comment: Thanks , so it's confirmed that the API does not exist for that task.

Answer (score 6):

As of [this commit](https://developer.blender.org/rBaf008f553293) you can use [`Context.selected_ids`](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.92/Python_API) (undocumented for now) to get references for all object types selected in the outliner. Notice that the context of [`selected_ids`](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.92/Python_API) attribute is restricted to the *Outliner* so you'd have to implement an *Operator*.

---

I'd also suggest use the `bl_rna.identifier` attribute to test against the actual type of object in order to filter the selection. Run the script, move your mouse over to the ouliner, press <kbd>F3</kbd> and type `Simple Outliner Op...` and hit <kbd>Return</kbd>:

```
import bpy

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "outliner.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Outliner Operator"
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.area.type == 'OUTLINER'

    def execute(self, context):
        objects_in_selection = {}
        for item in context.selected_ids:
            if item.bl_rna.identifier == "Collection":
                objects_in_selection.setdefault("Collections",[]).append(item.name)
            elif item.bl_rna.identifier == "Object":
                if item.type == 'MESH':
                    objects_in_selection.setdefault("Meshes",[]).append(item.name)
                elif item.type == 'LIGHT':
                    objects_in_selection.setdefault("Lights",[]).append(item.name)
                elif item.type == 'CAMERA':
                    objects_in_selection.setdefault("Cameras",[]).append(item.name)
            elif item.bl_rna.identifier == "Material":
                objects_in_selection.setdefault("Materials",[]).append(item.name)
        
        # Print the dict to the console
        print (objects_in_selection)
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Console Output: `{'Collections': ['Collection', 'Collection.001'], 'Cameras': ['Camera', 'Camera.001'], 'Meshes': ['Cube', 'Cube.001'], 'Lights': ['Light', 'Light.001']}`

Comment: Can be used in conjunction with the new batch remove _eg_ `bpy.data.batch_remove(context.selected_ids)`

Answer (score 3):

@brockmann's answer works perfect.
I just copied his functionality for an easier use for python beginners:

Here in addition is just an answer you can just execute by copy and paste without to execute the add-on in the outliner:

```
import bpy
from bpy import context

for window in context.window_manager.windows:
    screen = window.screen
    for area in screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'OUTLINER':
            with context.temp_override(window=window, area=area):
                objects_in_selection = {}
                for item in context.selected_ids:
                    if item.bl_rna.identifier == "Collection":
                        objects_in_selection.setdefault("Collections",[]).append(item.name)
                    elif item.bl_rna.identifier == "Object":
                        if item.type == 'MESH':
                            objects_in_selection.setdefault("Meshes",[]).append(item.name)
                        elif item.type == 'LIGHT':
                            objects_in_selection.setdefault("Lights",[]).append(item.name)
                        elif item.type == 'CAMERA':
                            objects_in_selection.setdefault("Cameras",[]).append(item.name)
                    elif item.bl_rna.identifier == "Material":
                        objects_in_selection.setdefault("Materials",[]).append(item.name)
                
                # Print the dict to the console
                a = objects_in_selection.get("Collections")
                if a:
                    print ("selected collections are", a)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code could be used to get the value of `context.selected_ids` without limiting an Operator's `execute()` to the Outliner area:

```
def get_outliner_area(context):
    for area in context.screen.areas:
        if area is None:
            continue
        if area.type != 'OUTLINER':
            continue
        return area

def get_outliner_window(area):
   for region in area.regions:
       if region.type != 'WINDOW':
           continue
       return region

# we will override context to be able to access selected_ids

# assuming that context is defined
outliner_area = get_outliner_area(context)
outliner_window = get_outliner_window(outliner_area)

# deprecated since 3.2 but easy to use
context_overridden = context.copy()
context_overridden['area'] = outliner_area
context_overridden['region'] = outliner_window

# @brockmann's solution can then be used to output a nice dictionary
print(context_overridden['selected_ids'])
```

Console output:
`[bpy.data.objects['Material'], bpy.data.objects['Camera'], bpy.data.objects['Material.001'], bpy.data.objects['Material.002'], bpy.data.objects['Material.003'], bpy.data.objects['Armature']]`

Comment: In Blender 3.5 it throws an error: `KeyError: 'selected_ids'` if you just run this as a script