# Query if selection is a collection

Tags: python, collections, select

I have troubling ensuring that my selection is a collection.

My code:

```
import bpy

# Set the area to the outliner
area = bpy.context.area
old_type = area.type 
area.type = 'OUTLINER'

#Get each selected data
ids = bpy.context.selected_ids
for x in ids:
    print(x.name)

# Reset the area 
area.type = old_type
```

This gives me all selected objects.

I thought I could compare it to all existing collections:

```
import bpy

for collection in bpy.data.collections:
    print(collection.name)
```

But like this I could run into problems when I have an object selected that has the same name as a collection.

So how do I get all selected collections?

Comment: `[c for c in context.selected_ids if c.bl_rna.identifier == "Collection"]`? From: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227832/how-to-get-a-list-of-selected-excluded-collections-in-the-outliner-using-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **p2or**!

This code works.

```
import bpy

# Set the area to the outliner
area = bpy.context.area
old_type = area.type 
area.type = 'OUTLINER'

for x in bpy.context.selected_ids:
    if x.bl_rna.identifier == 'Collection':
        print(x.name)

# Reset the area 
area.type = old_type
```

For you to run in the text editor, switch it to the outliner make your selection there, switch back to the text editor and run this code.