# How do I get the selected Assets in the Asset Browser using the API?

Tags: python, scripting, asset-browser

Similar to [Python : Get selected objects in outliner](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/203729/python-get-selected-objects-in-outliner)

How can one access the assets that are currently selected in the asset browser editor using the python API ?

I assume it should be available on a per-editor basis since, contrary to the outliner where selection state is shared between all editors, different asset browser editors can have different asset selection states :

[image]

Comment: i cannot even find the "right" area type  TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: enum "ASSET_BROWSER" not found in ('EMPTY', 'VIEW_3D', 'IMAGE_EDITOR', 'NODE_EDITOR', 'SEQUENCE_EDITOR', 'CLIP_EDITOR', 'DOPESHEET_EDITOR', 'GRAPH_EDITOR', 'NLA_EDITOR', 'TEXT_EDITOR', 'CONSOLE', 'INFO', 'TOPBAR', 'STATUSBAR', 'OUTLINER', 'PROPERTIES', 'FILE_BROWSER', 'SPREADSHEET', 'PREFERENCES')

Comment: have a look at `startup/bl_operators/assets.py`.  It looks like you need something like `active_asset = SpaceAssetInfo.get_active_asset(context)`  There only seems to be the concept of active and not selected?

Comment: @Chris Yeah it's not `.type` it's `.ui_type`... was fooled by it too !

Comment: @MartyFouts ooh neat I'll dig into that thanks !

Comment: It looks like it is not currently possible to gather a list of currently selected assets in the asset browser editor.

One can however get a handle on the currently selected asset with `context.asset_file_handle`, and only this one. But it seems unreliable at best and the documentation [explicitly states](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.context.html?highlight=asset_file_handle#bpy.context.asset_file_handle) that this member will be replaced in the future.

I'll wait for this feature to be implemented in one of the future versions then. :)

Comment: The quote from the docs: *"Avoid using this, it will be replaced..."* made my day :D

Comment: @brockmann Fast forward in 5 years when this quote is still there in the docs... xD

Comment: Well seems I was wrong, it is in the works : https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.AssetHandle.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Blender 4.0+

Blender 4.0 introduces [bpy.types.AssetRepresentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.AssetRepresentation.html#bpy.types.AssetRepresentation), [bpy.context.selected_assets](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.context.html#bpy.context.selected_assets), [bpy.context.asset](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.context.html#bpy.context.asset) we can use to our advantage.

```
import bpy


class PrintSelectedAssets(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "asset.print_selected_assets"
    bl_label = "Print Selected Assets"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.selected_assets

    def execute(self, context):
        for asset_representation in context.selected_assets:
            print(f"{asset_representation.full_path=}")
            print(f"{asset_representation.full_library_path=}")
            print(f"{asset_representation.id_type=}")
            print(f"{asset_representation.name=}")
            # This will be None if the asset is not located in current file :
            print(f"{asset_representation.local_id=}")
        print(context.asset)  # Active asset

        return {"FINISHED"}


def display_button(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(PrintSelectedAssets.bl_idname)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(PrintSelectedAssets)
    bpy.types.ASSETBROWSER_MT_editor_menus.append(display_button)


def unregister():
    bpy.types.ASSETBROWSER_MT_editor_menus.remove(display_button)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(PrintSelectedAssets)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

### Blender 3.6

I found the answer while researching [another answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/261226/86891).

It's actually an attribute of [File context](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.context.html?highlight=asset_file_handle#bpy.context.selected_asset_files) which unless I'm mistaken does require the piece of code to be executed inside the context of the asset browser.

Here's the slightly altered script that adds a button in the Asset Browser header that, when clicked, outputs some information about the selected assets in the console :

```
import bpy
from pathlib import Path


class PrintSelectedAssets(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "asset.print_selected_assets"
    bl_label = "Print Selected Assets"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.selected_asset_files

    def execute(self, context):
        current_library_name = context.area.spaces.active.params.asset_library_ref
        if current_library_name != "LOCAL":  # NOT Current file
            library_path = Path(context.preferences.filepaths.asset_libraries.get(current_library_name).path)

        for asset_file in context.selected_asset_files:
            if current_library_name == "LOCAL":
                print(f"{asset_file.local_id.name} is selected in the asset browser. (Local File)")
            else:
                asset_fullpath = library_path / asset_file.relative_path
                print(f"{asset_fullpath} is selected in the asset browser.")
                print(f"It is located in a user library named '{current_library_name}'")
            
        return {"FINISHED"}


def display_button(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(PrintSelectedAssets.bl_idname)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(PrintSelectedAssets)
    bpy.types.ASSETBROWSER_MT_editor_menus.append(display_button)


def unregister():
    bpy.types.ASSETBROWSER_MT_editor_menus.remove(display_button)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(PrintSelectedAssets)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: context should be the context of the asset browser? context.selected_assets won't work out of that context I think

Comment: @NoobCat well, yes, because you can have multiple asset browsers open at the same time with different selection states

Answer (score 1):

### How to get it from the window area

```
>>> bpy.context.screen.areas[3].spaces.active.params.filename
'geometry_nodes\\procedural_hair_node_assets.blend\\NodeTree\\Braid Hair Curves'
```

[image]

If the asset browser area on the window has been identified, it is useful to learn the information from the console.

In the example, it is "bpy.context.screen.areas[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4N0Z.png)", but the number will vary depending on the environment.

The area can be identified

by https://github.com/Pullusb/devTools

which is an add-on that provides a convenient button on the console.
[image]

### Acquire information via operator

We already have the code for the answer, but some of the context data accesses have "mechanisms that can only be accessed via the operator".

For example, the following access is only accessible on the operator and not in the area

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.FileSelectEntry.html

Therefore, it is necessary to set up an access button in the area from which to obtain the divestment.
Of course, if you place this button anywhere other than on the asset browser, it will not work.

```
import bpy
from pathlib import Path

breakpoint = bpy.types.BP_PT_bp.bp
class PrintSelectedAssets(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "asset.print_selected_assets"
    bl_label = "Print Selected Assets"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.selected_asset_files

    def execute(self, context):
        for asset in context.selected_asset_files:
            asset_re_path=asset.relative_path
            print("### asset path :",asset_re_path)
            
        return {"FINISHED"}


def display_button(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(PrintSelectedAssets.bl_idname)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(PrintSelectedAssets)
    bpy.types.ASSETBROWSER_MT_editor_menus.append(display_button)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(PrintSelectedAssets)
    bpy.types.ASSETBROWSER_MT_editor_menus.remove(display_button)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It works, but how to get all selected assets? It return only one (the last)...

Comment: @Bicukow  I have made an addition to my answer. Please check it.