# Change Asset Browser Catalog using python API

Tags: python, asset-browser

How can I change the focused catalog in the asset browser using Blender's Python API?

Thanks.

[image: Change Catalog]

Comment: Good question. This kind of info can usually be found in https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.SpaceFileBrowser.html#bpy.types.SpaceFileBrowser or https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.FileSelectParams.html#bpy.types.FileSelectParams but I'm afraid not in this case. I wonder if it's available to the API at all.

Comment: Swap [this link](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.FileAssetSelectParams.html#bpy.types.FileAssetSelectParams) and the second link of my previous comment.

Comment: @Gorgious, thanks I also found the docs for `FileAssetSelectParams`. I couldn't find any examples on how to use it.

Comment: Here's an example https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/261226/86891

Comment: thanks @Gorgious. I just looked at the post you referenced and tried setting         `context.area.spaces.active.params.catalog_id = 'CATALOG_ID'`. I get the error `AttributeError: bpy_struct: attribute "catalog_id" from "FileAssetSelectParams" is read-only` also tried setting `context.space_data.params.catalog_id` and got the same error.

Comment: Oh, right I didn't even see that parameter. Yes it is written that this is read-only in the docs. It looks like it's not available to the API...

Comment: It will be possible in Version 3.5. See https://developer.blender.org/rB80249c