# How do I access the list of selected assets from an event in python?

Tags: python, asset-browser

Key thing here is **from an event** - [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/249837/how-do-i-get-the-selected-assets-in-the-asset-browser-using-the-api) does a great job at explaining how to get the list from inside the asset browser window, which is not what I am looking to do (unless I'm missing something).

For context: I am trying to create an add-on that assigns the currently selected material asset to the current object(s) via a shortcut.

In other words - I'd like the user to be able to

- select a material
- select a mesh
- press Shift-Ctrl-A and assign the material to the mesh
- select another mesh
- press Shift-Ctrl-A and assign the material to the new mesh

in python I know

- how to assign a material to a mesh
- how to detect events

but I cannot for the life of me figure how to get the currently selected assets **from an event**. Bold because I am aware of [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/249837/how-do-i-get-the-selected-assets-in-the-asset-browser-using-the-api) on how do one gets the selected Assets in the Asset Browser using the API - but it doesn't seem to work unless I invoke the functionality from a button *inside the asset browser* (which is not what I am looking for).

I got this far:

```
import bpy
import os
from pathlib import Path

from bpy.props import (StringProperty,
                       BoolProperty,
                       IntProperty,
                       FloatProperty,
                       FloatVectorProperty,
                       EnumProperty,
                       PointerProperty,
                       )
from bpy.types import (Panel,
                       Menu,
                       Operator,
                       PropertyGroup,
                       )

class WM_OT_GetAssetContext(Operator):
    bl_label = "Get asset context"
    bl_idname = "wm.get_asset_context"
    pass

def cycle_all_areas(context):
    for screenArea in context.window.screen.areas:
        if screenArea.type == 'FILE_BROWSER':
            print('here')
            params = screenArea.spaces.active.params
            print(dir(params.bl_rna))
            # context.area = screenArea
            try:
                print(context.selected_asset_files)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                pass
            print(params.asset_library_ref)
            break


class WM_OT_ModalOperator(Operator):
    """Move an object with the mouse, example"""
    bl_idname = "object.modal_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Modal Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return True
    
    def modal(self, context, event):
        if not context.mode == "OBJECT":
            return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

        if event.type in ["A"] and event.value == "PRESS" and event.ctrl and event.shift:
            print("Assignment")
            print('area', context.area)
            print('space', context.space_data)
            cycle_all_areas(context)

        else:
            return {'PASS_THROUGH'}
                
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        print('been invoked')
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}



classes = (
    WM_OT_GetAssetContext,
    WM_OT_ModalOperator
)


def register():
    from bpy.utils import register_class

    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)

def unregister():
    from bpy.utils import unregister_class
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        unregister_class(cls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    bpy.ops.object.modal_operator('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

but all the lines printing area and space data output `None` and shen I press `shift+ctrl-A` I get the following error:

```
Context' object has no attribute 'selected_asset_files`
```

What's the right way to achieve this?

Comment: I think it's the same problem as when trying to access selected objects in the outliner, it's only possible from an operator run from within the context of the asset browser unfortunately. I'd love to be wrong though

Comment: @Gorgious - I was trying to work around it by detecting clicks on asset browser items, but that fails too

Comment: @Gorgious - yep: so you start a modal from an operator in the context, which is a bit mindboggling but it works - see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/262306/ for how