# How to select and unhide objects with Python

Tags: python, scripting

In Blender 2.91.2 I'm able to hide objects from the viewport by selecting them first and then using

```
mySelection = bpy.context.selected_objects
for obj in mySelection:
  obj.hide_set(True)
```

However, doing the reverse, by selecting them on the outliner doesn't seem as trivial

I'm aware of this [post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/203729/python-get-selected-objects-in-outliner), but still unable to formulate a solution.

I've tried using `mySelection = bpy.context.collection` but it seems a collection is not iterable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    if not obj.visible_get():
        obj.hide_set(False)
        obj.hide_viewport = False
        obj.select_set(True)
```