# Python: How to get selected collections list?

Tags: python

I can find only active collection with `bpy.context.collection`, there should be `bpy.context.selected_collections` similar to `bpy.context.selected_objects`.

How to get a list of selected collections?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python : Get selected objects in outliner](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/203729/python-get-selected-objects-in-outliner)

Comment: And how is `bpy.context.selected_ids` different from `bpy.context.selected_objects` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/293231/123423

```
import bpy
from bpy import context


def selected_collections(context):
    for area in context.screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'OUTLINER':
            with context.temp_override(area=area):
                return [item for item in context.selected_ids if isinstance(item, bpy.types.Collection)]


print(selected_collections(context))
```